# A function $f(x)$ such that $f(f(x))=\ln(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

How to find a continuous function $f(x)$ for $x > 12$, such that $f(f(x))=\ln(x)$? Preferably analytic too.

Comment: You can rewrite this as $e^{f(x)}=f(e^x)$ - maybe this helps. (let $y=e^x$, then $f(f(f(y)))=f(\ln y)=\ln(f(y)$ whence my equality).

Comment: But this will increase number of possible $f$'s since this equation has solution $f(x)=x$ while the initial one doesn't.

Comment: such function would be [half-iterate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-iterate) of $\ln x$; its inverse would be half-iterate of $\exp x$. For half-iterate of $\exp$, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12081

Comment: I suppose there is no such $f$ because the equation $f(x)=\exp(f(\ln x))$ has only the solution $f(x)=x$. I cannot prove this but I can show some estimate for $f$:
Suppose that such $f$ exists and is continuous. Let $e_n$ be the sequence $e_0=1$, $e_{n+1}=\exp(e_n)$. Let $f_n$ be the maximum of $f$ on $I_n=[e_n,e_{n+1}]$. Then for $x\in I_n$ we have $\ln x\in I_{n-1}$ so $f(x)=\exp(f(\ln x))\le \exp(f_{n-1})$, and $f_n\le \exp(f_{n-1}$. You start with $x>12$, so let my $n$ start with 3. Let $f_3=a$, then $f_n\le \exp(\dots \exp(a)\dots)$ with $\exp$ repeating $n-3$ times.

Comment: Since $x>\exp(\dots\exp(1)\dots)$ with $n-1$ exponents, we get $f_n\le (\ln(\ln x))^a$. Sorry, no more time now.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17605/how-to-solve-ffx-cosx/44727#44727