# How can a fractional logarithm be defined and calculated?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, soft-question, logarithms, regularization

**For context**, I am looking back at an [old question regarding a curious family of recursively defined logarithm towers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4024319/differentiable-properties-of-a-family-of-recursive-logarithmic-functions-what-d). What slightly unsettles me is the "discrete jump" between each curve as $k$ increases. I want to be able to patch it together by continuity in some sense.

---

The natural logarithm is well known mathematical function which for example is the functional inverse to the exponential function.

But how can we find or calculate a fractional logarithm function? $$\log^{1/k}(x) \text{ s.t. } (\log^{1/k} \underset{k\text{ times}}{\underbrace{\circ\cdots \circ}} \log^{1/k})(x) = \log(x)$$

We also want it to be "maximally smooth" in some sense.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/97646/42969.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17605/how-to-solve-ffx-cosx/44727#44727

Comment: @Anixx f(f(x)) = cos(x) is not easy to solve because it is "wrong way". But we can apply this method to f(f(x)) = sin(x) quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach without smoothing so far, but which seems to work well enough on small intervals.

We consider $x\to \log(1+x)=f(x) : x \in [0,1]$

1. Represent function decomposition as a matrix $M_f$ somehow.
2. Make guess of $M^{1/k}$, we make guess $M^{1/k} \approx M_{\frac{1}k f + \frac{k-1}k x}$ in other words a linear weighting between $f(x) = x$ and $f(x) = \log(x+1)$
3. Calculate error $e = |(M^{1/k})^k-M|$
4. Update guess based on $e$. Iterate from 3 until error "small enough".

Here is an approximation for $\log^{1/8}(1+x)$ :

[image]  [image]

We can see the uncertainty spreading with the matrix power. But the mean value hits real close to true. Max pointwise error circa $10^{-6}$. After some tuning and larger matrices we can expand to a larger domain:

[image]  [image]

Error residual : relative error below 1 per million.

[image]