# What basis of function is best for expressing fractional logarithm?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, soft-question, regression

**Background/context**: Having had some [numerical success trying to calculate a family of fractional logarithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4096829/how-can-a-fractional-logarithm-be-defined-and-calculated/4097942#4097942).

---

What would be the most reasonable basis of functions to try and express a fractional logarithm in ?

An ordinary family of polynomial seems unsuitable to build linear combinations with : the function is far too "close-to-linear" or what we shall call it.

My initial guess would be a linear function together with a set of fastly decaying functions, for example: $$\{x,1,x^{-1},\cdots ,x^{-k}\}$$
Maybe we can tie it to a partial Laurent expansion and some properties in Complex Analysis? Or will we need to dig deeper?